# Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0x7f0802ec

Tags: android, gradle, bundle, androidx, android-r8

After changing my android build Gradle version from 3.2.1 to 3.5.0, gradle version from 5.1.1 to 5.4 and updating support libraries to androidx. we have this new issue occurring i.e, Resource not found in high numbers.

Android-studio version is 3.5

Though the id(drawable) which is missing(lets say ImageA) is not used at that line number at all but exists there in folders."ImageB" is used at that line number. 
Drawable is stored as png in all respective folders(hdpi,mdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi,xxxhdpi)
ImageA and ImageB looks same but have different sizes in their respective folders.
we have tried changing the name of the resource but issue is still there and disabling r8 was not compiling/building the project.

we are not able to figure out whether this is an issue of **r8** or **bundle**.

Seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57206223/unable-to-find-resource-id-android-gradle-plugin-3-4-0) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21269502/android-resourcesnotfoundexception-resource-id-0x7f030027) post but they are related to string resource.

Comment: What is `0x7f0802ec` referring to? Open up your project `R.java` file and try searching for that resource, and check if it is defined in some versions but not in others. It may also be a vector drawable that an older device may not found on a notification, or on a normal image view.

Comment: If you already found the resource, some devices may check within `drawable` original folder instead of `drawable-xxhdpi` or anything else, first. Always have a copy on the original folder before publishing your app.